# форма валидации js

Tags: javascript

Есть собственно функция для проверки формы( элементы формы беру из полей text_area), по клику на сабмит. Застрял на том, что когда поля не заполненные, форма собственно не отправляется т.к. на выходе функции получаем false. Подскажите как можно доработать

```
window.onload = function() {  

    d.getElementById('contact_sent').onclick = function(){
    var error_msg = "fill all fields to send the form";      
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text_area');     
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if (elements[i].value == '' ){            
            elements[i].style.border = "2px solid orange";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = error_msg;           
        }
      } 
    return false;   
    }       
}
```

Comment: а что конкретно доработать?

Comment: функция должна проверить, введены ли все поля в форму, если нет - подсветить их и вывести ошибку. А получается, что после нажатия на сабмит , сама форма не отправляется , даже после того как все поля были уже введены

Comment: это все, потому что вы всегда _false_ возвращаете

Comment: в том то и дело, если возвращать false внутри цикла проверки, то незаполненные поля, будут подсвечивать по одному (сверху-вниз), по мере их ввода или же не ввода. Момент в том, что бы подсветка была на всех незаполненных полях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно выставляется флаг при проверке, и потом проверяется

```
d.getElementById('contact_sent').onclick = function(){
    var error_msg = "fill all fields to send the form";      
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text_area');     
    var hasError = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if (elements[i].value == '' ){     
            hasError = true;       
            elements[i].style.border = "2px solid orange";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = error_msg;           
        }
    } 
    return !hasError;   
}
```

Comment: спасибо за оперативное решение, теперь понятно